# Which partitioning program does Ubuntu use during installation?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Which partitioning algorithms use ubuntu during the installation, is it also available as a standalone application or command? Is it gparted?

Comment: Have a look at this http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/svn/debian-installer/installer/doc/devel/partman-auto-recipe.txt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The ubuntu installer uses `parted` - for the most part; The `parted` program in turn uses `fdisk` to create and modify partition tables and `mkfs` to create file systems.

GParted and its equivalents are merely front-ends to the linux partitioning tool kit. The Ubuntu installer is the same. It's a layer on top of parted and it executes it in the background, providing an easy to use abstraction of the plumbing behind it. The installer uses other programs, like `resize2fs` -to resize file systems - directly as well.

Comment: Parted does not use fdisk or mkfs.